# rust implement trait for multiple types

Tags: rust, struct, traits, rust-cargo

I am trying to implement a traits for multiple types at once, the only way I found to avoid code duplication is to transform all types to one common struct and implement the trait for that struct as below.

```
trait Increment {
    fn increment(&self) -> Option<String>;
}

struct NumberWrapper {
    number: String,
}

impl Increment for NumberWrapper {
    fn increment(&self) -> Option<String> {
        let num: Result<u64, _> = self.number.parse();
        match num {
            Err(_) => None,
            Ok(x) => Some((x + 1).to_string())
        }
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for NumberWrapper where T: ToString {
    fn from(input: T) -> NumberWrapper {
        NumberWrapper { number: input.to_string() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let number_u8: u8 = 10;
    println!("number_u8 is: {}", NumberWrapper::from(number_u8).increment().unwrap());
    let number_u32: u16 = 10;
    println!("number_u16 is: {}", NumberWrapper::from(number_u32).increment().unwrap());
    let number_u32: u32 = 10;
    println!("number_u32 is: {}", NumberWrapper::from(number_u32).increment().unwrap());
    let number_u64: u64 = 10;
    println!("number_u64 is: {}", NumberWrapper::from(number_u64).increment().unwrap());
}
```

Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Blanket implementations* can be used to implement traits for all types which satisfy some other trait(s). I'm not sure exactly what the trait in your example is meant to describe, but I hope the following example illustrates the idea.

```rust
use std::ops::Add;
use num::traits::One;

trait Increment {
    fn increment(&self) -> Option<String>;
}

impl<T> Increment for T
    where T: Add + Copy + One,
          <T as Add>::Output: ToString,
{
    fn increment(&self) -> Option<String> {
        Some((*self + One::one()).to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let number_u8: u8 = 10;
    println!("number_u8 is: {}", number_u8.increment().unwrap());
    let number_u32: u16 = 10;
    println!("number_u16 is: {}", number_u32.increment().unwrap());
    let number_u32: u32 = 10;
    println!("number_u32 is: {}", number_u32.increment().unwrap());
    let number_u64: u64 = 10;
    println!("number_u64 is: {}", number_u64.increment().unwrap());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this a little more elegantly come to my mind. First, I'm guessing you'd rather have your trait look something like this:

```
trait Increment {
    // It would probably be better to take `self` by value if you
    // just want this for numeric types which are cheaply copied,
    // but I'll leave it for generality.
    fn increment(&self) -> Option<Self> where Self: Sized;
}
```

I will assume this going forward (but please correct me).

The first way uses a pretty simple [macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html):

```
macro_rules! impl_increment {
    ($($t:ty),*) => {
        $(
            impl Increment for $t {
                fn increment(&self) -> Option<Self> {
                    self.checked_add(1)
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}
```

It only matches against one rule which reads any number of types separated by commas and implements the `increment` method for that type based on the [`checked_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.checked_add) method numeric primitives have in Rust. You can call this just like this:

```
// This will create an impl block for each of these types:
impl_increment!{u8, u16, u32, u64, i8, i16, i32, i64}

fn main() {
    let x = 41u32;
    assert_eq!(x.increment(), Some(42));
    let y = -60_000i64;
    assert_eq!(y.increment(), Some(-59_999));
    let z = 255u8;
    assert_eq!(z.increment(), None);
}
```

Or you can do it similarly to what you were already doing, by converting to and from a common type. In this case by using the `Into<u64>` and `TryFrom<u64>` traits which all the unsigned integer types narrower than `u64` implement:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

impl<T> Increment for T
where T: Copy + Into<u64> + TryFrom<u64>
{
    fn increment(&self) -> Option<Self> {
        let padded: u64 = (*self).into();
        TryFrom::try_from(padded + 1).ok()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 41u32;
    assert_eq!(x.increment(), Some(42));
    let y = 60_000u64;
    assert_eq!(y.increment(), Some(60_001));
    let z = 255u8;
    assert_eq!(z.increment(), None);
}
```

This has a lot more runtime overhead and doesn't generalize as nicely (won't work for signed integer types for example). So I'd go with the macro route.